# how to convert dataframes into list

Tags: python, mysql, database, list, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe into list and i have written the following but the output i get is list of list, what should i do to get just the list or how to convert the current output to list.
please check the image attached for the output and code below

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
region1 = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="xxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxx")
query1 = "SHOW DATABASES"
df1 = pd.read_sql(query1, region1)
print(df1.values.tolist())
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the current nested list to a single flattened list

```
from nltk import flatten

a = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
print(flatten(a))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
df1 = pd.read_sql(query1, region1)
res = []
for col in df.columns:
    res.append(df[col].values.tolist())
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[i[0] for i in df1.values.tolist()]
```

Output:

```
['atest', 'btest', 'ctest', 'information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'sakila', 'sys', 'telusko', 'world']
```

---

---

That is for when each list inside the list has only one element in it.

If there would be multiple things in each list:

```
[i for j in df1.values.tolist() for i in j]
```